# What's the best way to select max over multiple fields in SQL?

Tags: sql

The I kind of want to do is select max(f1, f2, f3). I know this doesn't work<strike>, but I think what I want should be pretty clear</strike> (see update 1).

I was thinking of doing select max(concat(f1, '--', f2 ...)), but this has various disadvantages. In particular, doing concat will probably slow things down. What's the best way to get what I want?

update 1: The answers I've gotten so far aren't what I'm after. max works over a set of records, but it compares them using only one value; I want max to consider several values, just like the way order by can consider several values.

update 2: Suppose I have the following table:

```
id class_name order_by1 order_by_2
 1          a         0          0
 2          a         0          1
 3          b         1          0
 4          b         0          9
```

I want a query that will group the records by class_name. Then, within each "class", select the record that would come first if you ordered by `order_by1` ascending then `order_by2` ascending. The result set would consist of records 2 and 3. In my magical query language, it would look something like this:

```
select max(* order by order_by1 ASC, order_by2 ASC)
from table
group by class_name
```

Comment: Actually, it's not entirely clear. Do you want the result where the total of f1, f2 & f3 is largest, or where the biggest of the 3 is largest, or what?

Comment: Can you give some example data, with the output you want? I think that's what we need to understand

Comment: You only get answers to the questions you actually ask. The answers here are fine, for the question you originally asked. In the future, try to avoid simplifying a question too much, and ask the question you actually want the answer to. "Can I eat fruit" is not a good question if you actually want to know if you can eat dogwood.

Comment: And note that your edit is contradictory. If you order by ascending on both fields, row 1 and 4 would actually come *first*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an answer I gave to another question: [SQL - SELECT MAX() and accompanying field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015689/sql-select-max-and-accompanying-field/2345892#2345892)

To make it work for multiple columns, add more columns to the inner select's ORDER BY.

Answer (score 6):

```
Select max(val)
From
(
  Select max(fld1) as val FROM YourTable
  union
  Select max(fld2) as val FROM YourTable
  union
  Select max(fld3) as val FROM YourTable
) x
```

**Edit:** Another alternative is:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(fld1) >= MAX(fld2) AND MAX(fld1) >= MAX(fld3) THEN MAX(fld1)
        WHEN MAX(fld2) >= MAX(fld1) AND MAX(fld2) >= MAX(fld3) THEN MAX(fld2)
        WHEN MAX(fld3) >= MAX(fld1) AND MAX(fld3) >= MAX(fld2) THEN MAX(fld3)
    END AS MaxValue
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Hmmm... interesting approach!

Comment: +1 for the `UNION`. It's surely more readable, however a trifle less efficient.

Comment: I'm wondering if UNION ALL instead of UNION would be more efficient.

Comment: I doubt if this works in vertica, which is a column based database

Answer (score 4):

I have one of these.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MathMax]  
(  
 @a int,  
 @b int  
)  
RETURNS int  
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
BEGIN  
 IF @a IS NULL AND @b IS NULL   
  RETURN 0  

 IF @a IS NULL   
  RETURN @b  

 IF @b IS NULL   
  RETURN @a  

 IF @a < @b   
  RETURN @b  

 RETURN @a  
END
```

Then I can do SELECT dbo.MathMax(dbo.MathMax(MAX(f1), MAX(f2)), MAX(f3)) FROM T1

I believe this performs about the same as the CASE while being more readable, and performs much better than the multi-UNION (even the slightly more efficient UNION ALL).

Comment: This is THE BEST ANSWER!!! from jpj625.

It is beyond me why people will go the convoluted route... of UNION or UNIONALL or CASE statements..

I needed this badly... and tested it out with both int and datetime... works flawlessly with really high performance...

5 STARS to this. Thank you jpj625.

I am an Access 2010 user.. and i copied a similar function from web 

http://allenbrowne.com/func-09.html

for Access Module.. and was wondering SQL Server could do something similar.. and finally found this. BRAVO!!!

Comment: This will perform like crap, because scalar UDFs get called for each row, like a cursor.  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/08/04/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You would group by your *class* (could be multiple columns) and use a subselect within the column list that uses an ordinary `order by` in combination with `limit 1`.