# DB2 get max date of four dates query

Tags: db2

I want to get greater date from four date columns and fields can be NULL.
Please help me to write a query for this. 
Example:

select max(date1, date2, date3, date4) from table A where tag_id='xxxxx'

Answer (score 0):

You can work with unions which combine your query results and then get the max date of the combined columns

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183097/whats-the-best-way-to-select-max-over-multiple-fields-in-sql) is the same question asked in another post

Hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(max_date) from 
    (select date1 max_date from table A where tag_id='xxxxx'
    union all
    select date2 from table A where tag_id='xxxxx'
     union all
    select date3 from table A where tag_id='xxxxx'
    union all
    select date4 from table A where tag_id='xxxxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN date1 >= date2 AND date1 >= date3 THEN date1
        WHEN date2 >= date1 AND date2 >= date3 THEN date2
        WHEN date3 >= date1 AND date3 >= date2 THEN date3
        ELSE                                        date1
    END AS RecentDate
FROM table A
WHERE A.tag_id='xxxxx'
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your example query?

MAX() (and MIN() for that matter) are a bit unusual....they exists as both an aggregate function operating on multiple rows and a scalar function operating on multiple columns.

The works fine for me on DB2 for IBM i:
`select max(dte1,dte2,dte3,dte4) from qtemp.test`