# Select Max Date in Year Month Day Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, max

I have a table that I drew the following sample from:

```
Item    <other columns> year month day
----    -- ------------ ---- ----- ---
VX4O    GL 630.5938     2012 7     20
BX2T    GL 0            2012 7     13
MWB806I GL 92004.72     2012 6     15
4XU     GL 17.125       2012 7     20
VL4O    GL 130.5        2012 7     20
MWB806I GL 92004        2012 10    26
MWB806I GL 92005        2012 11    30
3PU     GL 25           2012 7     20
VC4O    GL 630.6094     2012 7     20
MWB806I GL 92005        2012 11    2
```

The first column is Item, the last three columns are year, month, day.

How do I select the max date per item?

Comment: Have a look at this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015689/sql-select-max-and-accompanying-field/2345892#2345892

Comment: No, Its in a table in a SQL database

Comment: Is is a table with multiple fields or a single field with a comma delimited string?

Comment: @Jake1164 "the last three ***columns*** are year, month, day."

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Item, MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM([year]) 
  + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM([month]), 2) 
  + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM([day], 2)
)
FROM dbo.table
GROUP BY Item;
```

Now you really should consider fixing this schema. Why are you storing year/month/day separately? All it does is make calculations like this one much more difficult, and prevents any proper validation (you can have check constraints for basic stuff, but these are much more complex for things like leap years). And it doesn't save you any space (in fact you lose space if month/day are int, or if you can use smalldatetime).

Comment: This only works if Item is a separate field, not a single comma delimited string.

Comment: @Jak1164 it's logical to assume that because the OP stated the last three values are individual columns, that in spite of the formatting we are talking about individual columns here.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have too much control over the date format.  It is a data dump from an application that I cannot change....

Comment: @Flashgordan that doesn't mean the table you use has to match the data dump format. You can put their data into a staging table and then store it properly in your own table.

Comment: By storing it properly I presume you mean storing the data in a date time field? How would you create this from these three fields?

Comment: The same way I convert it in the query above: `INSERT dbo.real_table(dt) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(...) + ...) FROM dbo.staging_table;`